# Video not embedding in PDF using latex?

Tags: video

I have used the code below:

```
\section[]{ }
\begin{frame}{Make Up LO'real}
\begin{center}

\includemedia[
transparent,
passcontext,
addresource=MakeUpGenius.mp4,
flashvars={source=MakeUpGenius.mp4},
]{\color{blue}\framebox[0.4\linewidth][c]{Applause}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

but nothing come out? Just a box with text inside it in the PDF. I attached the output.

[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you viewing this. Which programme? Hardly any of the many pdf viewers support embedded video so the choice of viewer matters

Comment: The Adobe that i have is : Acrobat Reader DC also i have downloaded the adobe flash player ?

Comment: First, change `APlayer.swf` --> `VPlayer.swf`. Then, check that you have installed FlashPlayer for Firefox. Do the videos in the `media9` manual play?

Comment: The video is Mp4, and  in its property is played with Windows Media Player. I have never used media9, it is package ? !! and Iam using chrome not Firefox ?

Comment: Iam getting this message : Please Install the required version Flash player? I do not know what is the required version ?  https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

Comment: So, on the Adobe page you have linked, in the 2nd drop-down box, select the FlashPlayer for Firefox (NPAPI).